# Trying to upgrade to Android Studio 2.3.3; SDK looping between errors, not finishing; can't find adb.exe

Tags: android-studio, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade to Android Studio 2.3.3; SDK looping between errors, not finishing, repeating 4 screens, unable to find `adb.exe.`.

If I try to use AS, I get "`adb.exe`" not found and it's not in `C:\Users\Dov\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools` or anywhere else I've directed Search. A download called `Everything` didn't find it either.

*** EDIT *** `Everything` took a LONG time but found plenty of copies, including recent:

[image]

*** End edit ***

[image]

[image]

One time I got the message below, so I allowed it to kill the PROCESS, since the other option was to Cancel and I felt it was making progress. But now can't find `adb.exe`:

[image]

I don't know why `Malwarebytes` had it locked. I exited that program but updating still loops as shown above.

When I try to use AS, I did `Clean`, `Build` and then tried to `Run` my project. `Gradle` tells me this

`6:20 PM    Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]`

`6:20 PM    Gradle build finished in 4s 569ms`

`6:20 PM    IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb`

This popped up so I ran it:
[image]
Same result with 6 conflicts without resolution. Last line of SDK Quickie Instal says "Stopping ADB...:

**I am clueless about how to solve this, so I guess I should just un- and re-install AS 2.3.3.** Do  you agree? Or is there a way to get around this without knowing where `adb.exe` is? (BTW, I've exited Malwarbytes before last install attempt.)

`SDK` path is `C:\users\me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`.

Answer (score 0):

I found several recent copies of `adb.exe` in four folders and stuck one in `C:\Users\Dov\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`. To my surprise and joy, I can now compile and debug in AS 2.3.3.

I added the path `C:\Users\Dov\AppData\Local\Android\` to Excluded folders in Malwarebytes so it shouldn't lock it again and screw up upgrading the SDK.

I'll be back to say what happened during SDK upgrade.

*edit*

Same 6 errors BUT I canceled and the installer continued. Now:

[image]